# Using Clerk's `ClerkExpressRequireAuth` in a NestJS guard

Tags: nestjs, clerk, nestjs-jwt

I'm having trouble using the resolve(true) in a nestjs auth guard with Clerk's middleware implementation

```
@Injectable()
export class UserAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  private readonly requireAuth = ClerkExpressRequireAuth({

  });
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    const next = context.switchToHttp().getNext();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.requireAuth(request, response, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(new UnauthorizedException(err.stack));
        } else {
          resolve(true)
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

If there is an error (invalid jwt token), the guard works well, returning the stack below

```
{
    "message": "Error: Unauthenticated\n    at UserAuthGuard.requireAuth (/@/node_modules/@clerk/clerk-sdk-node/src/clerkExpressRequireAuth.ts:60:12)",
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "statusCode": 401
}
```

However, if correct token is passed, all i get is an empty body with a 401 code
[image]

i have tried using `resolve(true)`, and `return true;`, all i get is the empty response. Which configs am i missing

Comment: Are you certain that when you pass a valid token `err` is not possibly coming back as `{}` instead of `null` or `undefined` and being evaluated as `truthy` causing `reject(new UnuahtorizedException(undefined))` to be called?